# Why sometimes the mapreduce Average Reduce Time is a negative number?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I run a mapreduce job on a hadoop cluster. The job's running time I saw in browser at master:8088 and master:19888 (job history server web UI) are shown below：

master:8088

[image: master:8088]

master:19888

[image: master:19888]

I have two questions:

1. Why are the elapsed times from two pictures different?
2. Why sometimes the  Average Reduce Time is a negative number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `Average Reduce Time` is based on the times the previous tasks (shuffle/merge) took to finish and not necessarily the amount of time the reduce actually took to run.

Looking at this [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/hs/webapp/dao/JobInfo.java) you can see the relevant calculations occurring around line 300.

```
if (attempt.getState() == TaskAttemptState.SUCCEEDED) {
  numReduces++;
  avgShuffleTime += (attempt.getShuffleFinishTime() - attempt.getLaunchTime());
  avgMergeTime += attempt.getSortFinishTime() - attempt.getShuffleFinishTime();
  avgReduceTime += (attempt.getFinishTime() - attempt.getSortFinishTime());
}
```

Followed by:

```
if (numReduces > 0) {
  avgReduceTime = avgReduceTime / numReduces;
  avgShuffleTime = avgShuffleTime / numReduces;
  avgMergeTime = avgMergeTime / numReduces;
}
```

Looking at your numbers, they seem to be generally in-line with this approach to calculating the run times (everything converted to seconds):

`Total Pre-reduce time = Map Run Time + Ave Shuffle + Ave Merge`
`143 = 43 + 83 + 17`

`Ave Reduce Time = Elapsed Time - Total Pre-reduce`
`-10 = 133 - 143`

So looking at how long the `Map`, `Shuffle` and `Merge` took compared with the `Elapsed` we end up with a negative number close to your `-8`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, only for question 1!

I see a difference in "Submitted" and "Started" of 8 seconds in the second picture, while the time "Started" in the first picture is equal to the "Submitted" time of the second. I guess this covers the 8-second difference that you see as "Elapsed" time.

I am very curious for the second question as well, but it may not be a coincidence that it is also 8 seconds.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I think  your answer for question 1 is right,but for the question 2,I think it is just a coincidence that it is also 8 seconds,because I have tested  an other MapReduce job,and it  shows the Average Reduce Time is random.